# The dimension of the orthogonal complement

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, vector-spaces, bilinear-form

> Let $f$ : ${R}^4\times{{R}^4}$ $\longrightarrow$ ${R}$ be a bilinear
> map
>
> such that $f(($x$,$y$,$z$,$t$), ($a$,$b$,$c$,$d$))$ = $a$$x$ + $b$$y$ + $c$$z$
>
> $1$. If $M$ = {($x$,$y$,$z$,$t$) | $x$ + $y$ - $z$ = $0$ and $t$ = $x$ +
> $y$ } is a subspace of ${R}^4$ then
>
> what is the dimension of $M^\top$ + $M$ and $M^\top$ $\cap$ $M$
>
> $2$ . If $T$ = { ($1$,$1$,$1$,$1$) , ($1$,$1$,$1$,$0$) ,
> ($1$,$1$,$0$,$0$) , ( $1$ ,$0$ , $0$ , $0$ ) } and $S$ = {$e_{1}$ ,
> $e_{2}$ , $e_{3}$ , $e_{4}$ } are basis of ${R}^4$
>
> then find the matrix $A$ and matrix $B$ such that the matrix
> representation  $M($f$,$T$,$S$)$ = $A$ $M($f$,$T$,$S$)$ $B^\top$ where
> $B$ is regular matrix

Edit :
For the first part I found that

$M^\top$ = { ($1$ , $1$ , $-1$ , $x$ ) | $x$ $\in$ $R$ }

so { ($1$ , $1$ , $-1$ , $0$) , ($0$ , $0$ , $0$ , $1$)} is a basis of $M^\top$

and the set { ($1$ , $0$ , $1$ , $1$) , ($0$ , $1$ , $1$ , $1$) is a basis of $M$

and $M^\top$ $\cap$ $M$  is empty set but I know that empty set is not subspace what I can say about it's dimension $?$

For the second part I don't know how I can start any help please,

Answer (score 1):

In general the intersection $M\cap M^{\bot}$ is $\{0\}$, not the empty set since for $v\in M\cap M^{\bot}$ you have $||v||^2=\langle v,v \rangle = 0 \Rightarrow v=0$ by assumption and the other inclusion is trivial.
Thus the intersection has dimension $0$

Comment: But to be an element of $M^\top$ in my solution it must has the form (1 , 1 , −1 , x ) so what is the wrong ?

Comment: Any linear subspace must contain the zero vector, so that description of $M^\bot$ can't be true. I just noticed that you wrote $M^\bot$ in two ways that are not the same. If $\{(1,1,-1,0), (0,0,0,1) \}$ is a basis of $M^\bot$ we have
$$\alpha (1,1,-1,0) + \beta (0,0,01) \in M^\bot$$ for all real numbers $\alpha,\beta$ (in particular for $\alpha=\beta=0$) but this is a much larger space than just vectors of the form $$(1,1,-1,x)$$

Comment: $M^\top$ = { (a,b,c,d) | f((a,b,c,d),(x,y,z,t)) = 0 } now when ax+by+cz = 0 at a = b = c = 0 and at a = 1, b= 1 , c = -1 so $M^\top$ = { (1,1,-1,x) , (0,0,0,0) , (0,0,0,y) } now is it true ?